# Asterisk WARNING[4695]: chan_dahdi.c:12320 do_monitor: Read failed with -1: Invalid argument

Tags: asterisk, telephony

when I restart Asterisk and connect to the Asterisk console with a

```
asterisk -rv
```

Asterisk is spitting thousands of

```
WARNING[4695]: chan_dahdi.c:12320 do_monitor: Read failed with -1: Invalid argument
```

after some minutes of this crazy spitting of messages it quits with a

```
*CLI> 
Disconnected from Asterisk server
Asterisk cleanly ending (0).
Executing last minute cleanups
```

a dmesg shows:

```
[ 3561.591539] asterisk[4695]: segfault at b3150fec ip b73a4b8d sp b3150ff0 error 6 in libc-2.19.so[b7334000+1a8000]
```

I have no idea how to deal with this and find no similar error anywhere.
I am using a Digium TDM410P telephony card with 2 FXO and two FXS interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Dahdi linux driver < 2.10.0.1 is incompatible with linux kernel 3.16+

See complete problem description and fix in Asterisk Jira:
https://issues.asterisk.org/jira/browse/DAHLIN-340